# If 'some element' in a specific position of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
MyList = [('name1', 'surname1', 'age1'), ('name2', 'surname2', 'age2'), ...]
```

I would like to make a check "if 'name2' in MyList, something like:

```
if 'name2' in MyList[?][0]: 
    print "do something"
```

If I would write `if 'name2' in MyList[0]` I would be accessing the element ('name1', 'surname1', 'age1') while what I meant is to access *the element at position 0 of every tuple in the list*. I guess there is a syntaxis to do that but I'm a newbie and cannot find it online myself, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function and a generator function, like this

```
if any("name2" in name for name, surname, age in my_list):
    # do something
```

Here all the elements of tuples are unpacked to `name, surname, age` while iterating. So, we can simply check if `name2` is in name. This is the same as writing

```
if any("name2" in current_item[0] for current_item in my_list):
```

This will be efficient, as it yields `True` immediately after there is a match, rest of the items need not be checked.

If you are looking for a way to compare two strings, you should be using `==` operator, like this

```
if any("name2" == name for name, surname, age in my_list):
# do something
```

Comment: why '"name2" in name'? Should it not be '"name2" == name'?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik That is what he has in the question. I ll include this suggestion also in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds that you could benefit from using dictionaries:

```
my_dict = dict( (x[0],(x[1],x[2])) for x in MyList)
```

Then you can check for existence `'names2' in my_dict` and also access directly the data `my_dict['names2']`

Comment: This could have the problem of having to create a new dict for comparing surnames and a new dict for comparing ages. Might go out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient method, but you could use this.

```
>>>MyList = [('name1', 'surname1', 'age1'), ('name2', 'surname2', 'age2'), ...]
>>> if 'name2' in zip(*MyList)[0]:
              #do something.
```

The point is it creates a transpose of the original list. **Caveat**: All tuples have to be of same length to avoid data loss.

EDIT: Official [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for zip.

Official [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for `*` operator used in unpacking argument lists.